# Send different emails using different SMTP Settings in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, smtp, actionmailer, email

I have an application using which i send an emails to users using sendgrid settings.

Now what i want certain email such as Exception Occur Emails should go using my smtp settings and not by send grid settings.

How Can i achieve this?

I set my email settings in enviorment.rb as following

```
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.default_charset = "utf-8"
    config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address        => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["address"],
    :port           => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["port"],
    :domain         => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["domain"],
    :authentication => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["authentication"],
    :user_name      => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["user_name"],
    :password       => @@config_settings["email_settings"]["password"]
  }
```

Where should i set the other email settings & use it for certain Action Mailer methods.

Also it should not affect the other Action Mailer methods.

Comment: Check this article: [Using multiple SMTP accounts with Rails & ActionMailer](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/03/using-multiple-smtp-accounts-w.html).